# how to operate a dynamice table in trigger with mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, triggers

I need to write a trigger that will update a record in another table. the table name is dynamic.

the trigger I've created looks like this:

```
BEGIN
   if new.status = 1 then 
       UPDATE NEW.tablename SET f1 = NULL WHERE id_ = old.pid;
   END if;
END
```

but the update sql can not run

Can someone please help me with the SQL here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column value as a table name. Only dynamic SQL can - but it is not allowed in a trigger.

The only visible way to perform the task is

```sql
BEGIN
   if new.status = 1 then 
       CASE NEW.tablename WHEN 'table1'
                          THEN UPDATE table1 SET f1 = NULL WHERE id_ = old.pid;
                          WHEN 'table2'
                          THEN UPDATE table2 SET f1 = NULL WHERE id_ = old.pid;
                          ...
                          END CASE;
   END if;
END
```